# Login a website which uses OAuth 2.0 using Python

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, python-requests, web-crawler

I'm trying to automate the login process using Python script or Postman but failed. Assume I want to login a site called `crawled-site.com`. After I click the login button the site will direct me to the login page accompanied with `client_id`, `scope`, `response_type`, `redirect_url` and so forth. Then I am required to enter my username and password to login. After logged in, I will obtain the code `mysite.com/callback?code=xxxxx`. However, I was stuck because I had no `client_secret` to request the token as I am not the owner of the `crawled-site.com`. Although the site will redirect me to the home page after I logged in, I don't know how to reproduce this process. Is it possible to get the token without `client_secret`? How should I use Python to log in a website that uses OAuth 2.0? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get the token without client_secret?

Yes, but the client must have a valid client_id and redirect_uri. [See this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595392/oauth2-without-client-secret-possible-phishing#answer-47156625)

> How should I use Python to log in a website that uses OAuth 2.0?

Since you already tagged `python-requests` [check out requests-oauthlib](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib). There are multiple possible workflows you could do. [Maybe check out the Backend Application Flow](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2_workflow.html#backend-application-flow)

Comment: The backend flow linked uses a client id which OP does not want. It would help to improve your answer instead of just linking to another SO answer since it doesn't answer how to do this using python.